# finding smallest and second smallest value of an array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I have an array that will contains 5 random numbers between 0 to 99. I want to find the smallest and second smallest number of that array, I have the code below but it will not work if the **first** element is the smallest number. How can I fix this? Thank you for any help! :)

```
int numbers[5];

int main()
{
srand(time(NULL));

for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
    numbers[i]=rand()%100;
    cout<<numbers[i]<<" ";
}

cout<<endl;

int smallest = numbers[0], secondSmallest=numbers[0];

for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
    if(numbers[i]<smallest){
        secondSmallest=smallest;
        smallest=numbers[i];
    }
    else if(numbers[i]<secondSmallest)
        secondSmallest=numbers[i];
}
cout<<"Smallest number is : "<<smallest<<endl;
cout<<"Second smallest number is : "<<secondSmallest<<endl;
}
```

EDIT : this need to be done without sorting the array based on the requirements of the assignment.

Comment: Init the variables to std::numeric_limits<int>::max() ?

Comment: May the array be re-ordered?

Comment: sugestion: use two for loops.

Comment: @Paolo.Bolzoni thank you, can you explain what does this code means?

Comment: @user2079303 sorry I forgot to add in the info, i was asked to do this without sorting the array.

Comment: Another way is doing like this: `int smallest = numbers[0], secondSmallest=numbers[1]; if (secondSmallest < smallest) std::swap(secondSmallest, smallest);` and start the loop from position 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yet another way to get this done without using two loops. Takes care of duplicates.

```
    int smallest = numbers[0],secondSmallest = numbers[0];
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        if(numbers[i]>smallest){
            if(numbers[i]<secondSmallest || smallest==secondSmallest){
                secondSmallest = numbers[i];
            }
        }else{
            if(secondSmallest>smallest && numbers[i]!=smallest){
                secondSmallest=smallest;
            }
            smallest = numbers[i];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If `numbers[0]` is the smallest then you know some other index has to be the second smallest.  Because of that we can use `secondSmallest=numbers[1]`.  Even if `numbers[1]` is the smallest

```
if(numbers[i]<smallest){
    secondSmallest=smallest;
    smallest=numbers[i];
}
```

changes `secondSmallest` to what `smallest` was, which would be `numbers[0]`, so it will still work.

We could also use [`std::numeric_limits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits) from [`<limits>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/limits) and set both variables to `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()` which will make them the largest value an `int` can store.  None of the variables in the array can be greater than that so they will either be equal to or smaller than it.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this in your else if:

```
else if(numbers[i]<secondSmallest && numbers[i] != smallest)
        secondSmallest=numbers[i];
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try to initialize secondSmallest number to be largest number, like 99 here. 
( even if all the 5 numbers random to be 99, the second smallest number still be 99.)

Comment: Even `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()` better.

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved in two ways.

You can initialize `smallest` and `secondSmallest` with the biggest number possible:

```
#include<limits>

// ...
int smallest = std::numeric_limits<int>::max(), secondSmallest = smallest;
```

Then I'd change the if statement inside your loop like this:

```
for( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
    //          ^^^^^ use a std::vector and change that to i < numbers.size()
    if ( numbers[i] < secondSmallest ) {
        if ( numbers[i] < smallest ) {
            secondSmallest = smallest;
            smallest = numbers[i];
        } else {
            secondSmallest = numbers[i];
        }
    }
}
```

---

Otherwise if you are sure to have at least 2 elements in your container, you can start comparing the first ones:

```
int smallest = numbers[0], secondSmallest = numbers[1];
if ( numbers[1] < numbers[0] ) {
    secondSmallest = numbers[0];
    smallest = numbers[1];
}
```

Then the starting condition of the loop can be changed:

```
for( int i = 2; i < numbers.size(); i++ ) { ...
//          ^^^ we have already compared the first ones
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved by finding smallest and secondSmallest separately and initially assign them different values.

Here is the code:

```
int smallest = numbers[0], secondSmallest=99; //max value to secondSmallest

for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
    if(numbers[i]<smallest){
        smallest=numbers[i];
    }
}

for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
    if(numbers[i]<secondSmallest && numbers[i]!=smallest){
        secondSmallest=numbers[i];
    }
}
```